# Django - Display filtered sum of a field from a model on template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model (camisaEvento) that have a One To Many relationship with (quantidadeEvento). I want to display on the template the sum of a field in quantidadeEvento but only for the elements of a determined record on camisaEvento.

On the view i have the following, which are passed to the template to a render_to_response:

```
camisasEvento = camisaEvento.objects.all()
quantidadesEvento = quantidadeEvento.objects.all()
```

I'm making a table for each record of camisaEvento, and in the end i want it to have a cell that is the sum of a determined field on the quantidadeEvento but only for the current camisaEvento record on the for loop, so in the template i have the following:

```
{% for camisa_do_evento in camisasEvento %}
<table>
    <td>...<td>
    <td>...<td>
    .
    .
    .
    <td>The sum should be in here</td>
<table>
{% endfor %}
```

What is the best way to do this? I know this is probably simple, but i'm quite new to programming and Django.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a property on camisaEvento?

```
class camisaEvento(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def sum_quantity(self):
        # just guessing, don't know exactly what you need
        # it's using python's list comprehension, but you can use a more explicit
        # syntax if you're not familiar with this one
        return sum([obj.field_to_sum for obj in               
                    quantidadeEvento.objects.filter(fk_field=self.id)])
```

and then, in your template:

```
{% for camisa_do_evento in camisasEvento %}
    {{ camisa_do_evento.sum_quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

How does this work: I'm creating a method on the `camisaEvento` class that fetches all the `quantidadeEvento` for that class and sums up their field (that's "fantasy" logic, since I don't exactly know what you need to sum). Then, in your template, you just call that method as if it was a real property of your camisaEvento class

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/) to calculate the sum, in the view:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
camisasEvento = camisaEvento.objects.all().annotate(quantidade_sum=Sum('quantidadeevento__field_to_sum')
```

where 'field_to_sum' is the field you want to add up. This creates an attribute called `quantidade_sum`  on each `camisasEvento` that contains the sum of the related fields.

Note that in your template, you can iterate through the quantidadeEvento objects related to each camisaEvento by using the reverse relationship:

```
<table>
    {% for camisa_do_evento in camisasEvento %}
    <tr>
        {% for quantidade_evento in camisa_do_evento.quantidadeEvento.all %}
          <td>{{ quantidade_evento.my_field }}<td>
        {% endfor }
        <td>Sum: {{ camisa_do_evento.quantidade_sum }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
<table>
```